# Entering hash key on Word running on Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, virtual-machine, microsoft-word-2007

I have a document open in Word 2007 on Windows XP running within Vmware Fusion, hosted from Mac OS X 10.5 and using a UK keyboard. How do I enter the #(hash) key? I'm reduced to choosing it from the Insert>Symbol menu item.

I've already tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> without any luck.

**Edit:**  I'm on a Macbook. I'm running Vmware Fusion 2.0.4(159196).

Comment: For this kind of question can you use the <kdb> HTML tag for the keys: e.g: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

The Hash key (#) is effectively entered by using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> (either left or right). However, under Windows XP and VMWare Fussion, <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> is probably mapped to Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd> (which wouldn't be the same).

Therefore I suggest you try with the <kbd>right alt</kbd> on your Mac, and then <kbd>3</kbd> (which should print the # symbol).

This works on my Spanish keyboard, but as far as I can remember, US Layout has the same symbols under the numbers (or most of them). I can only imagine that UK layout is more or less the same thing, sans a few differences.

Comment: The UK laptop keyboards don't have a right alt key. The question doesn't mention a model type, so this may not be a solution if it's a laptop

Comment: I'm on a Macbook, and no this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Didn't work for me :-(

Answer (score 4):

Shift + 3 works for me. I am using a Mac bought in the UK, so the keyboard may differ. I use VMWare Fusion 4.10 and Windows 7 32 bit. This did work in notepad though.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to get it to work by pressing CMD-\

I've then mapped Alt-3 to CMD-\ using the VMWare fusion options

Comment: Works on a UK MacbookPro

Comment: 2nded - this works on VMWare Fusion/Win8.1/UK

Answer (score 1):

Found it after about 2 hours of trying...

For UK Mac users running windows **the # "hash key" is the "backslash key"** next to the enter key.